# didFinishLoadForFrame for WKWebView

Tags: swift, cocoa, webview, wkwebview

I was using didFinishLoadForFrame for webView component in my previous Cocoa project.

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

Now, webView is deprecated and I need to use WKWebView and there's no similar method.

Any opinion for handling frame loads with WKWebView will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` of `WKNavigationDelegate`. Then access to the `webView.webFrme`.